# Highlight row left and column up from pointer on hover

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

In a table on a `hover` event I would like everything **left** of the mouse in the `row` to highlight and everything **up** in the `column` from the mouse to highlight.

Any ideas how to do this in CSS or JS?

Comment: Please show what your previous attempts at doing this were. You can post some code of what you've tried so far, or perhaps link to some sites you've found. Try doing some research before asking your question here.

Comment: @Joey While I agree, I welcome "How do I do this" questions as long as they don't expect us to write 10k lines of code. In any case, this is unclear.

Comment: Well I could've taken up space by saying I've googled for the past 15 minutes looking for something relevant and am coming up short. I had no clue as to how to start. So I came here asking for ideas or suggestions. I appreciate the fellow who answered with code, however, that isn't what I came looking for. I understand it's probably frustrating to see questions like mine but I was merely asking for some guidance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is my solution to your problem. First on mouseenter (fyi `hover` isn't an event, it's `mouseenter`) of every `td` we're going get the target `td` of the mouse pointer and just iterate backwards on the `tr`'s and use `prevAll` to get all the `td`'s to the left of the hovered td.

```
$('table td').on('mouseenter mouseleave', function(e){
    var $tr, index;
    if(e.type === 'mouseenter'){
        $tr = $(e.target).parents('tr:first');
        index = $('td', $tr).index($(e.target));
        $(e.target).prevAll().addClass('highlight');
        $tr.prevAll().each(function(){
            $('td:eq('+index+')', this).addClass('highlight');
        });
    }else{
        $('.highlight').removeClass('highlight');
    }
});
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/8Exar/3/)